# How to use mixins properly

Tags: django

Please, help to understand, why the following doesn't work for me.
So, I need display information on a page from logged in user.
In order not to retype code in every view I decided to create a mixin.

```
class MyMixin(object):
  def my_view(self):
    args = {}
    args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
    args['first_name'] = auth.get_user(request).first_name
    args['last_name'] = auth.get_user(request).last_name
    return args

class someview (TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin, MyMixin):
  template_name = 'index.html
```

But this doesn't show anything in a template.

```
{{ first_name }}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the `args`?  Where is `my_view` being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways of getting these "context variables" into your template:

1. Your [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) already includes [`ContextMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin). So you could simply override `ContextMixin`'s `get_context_data` method for that view, like this:

   ```
   class someview (TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
       template_name = 'index.html

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(someview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['username'] = self.request.user.username
           context['first_name'] = self.request.user.first_name
           context['last_name'] = self.request.user.last_name
           return context
   ```
2. It seems that what you're actually looking for is a more DRY method, not necessarily a mixin. In that case, you should use write your own [`context_processor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

   context_processors.py:

   ```
   def extra_context(request):                                                         
       args = {}
       args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
       args['first_name'] = auth.get_user(request).first_name
       args['last_name'] = auth.get_user(request).last_name
       return args
   ```

   settings.py:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (your_app.context_processors.extra_context,)
   ```

   This second method will add these three context variables to every template in your app.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! Second method is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.